# Is it possible to prevent TextEdit's "The file has been changed" dialog from appearing unnecessarily?

Tags: macos, textedit, dialog

Every so often, I  will be doing something on my computer (e.g., in Google Chrome), when an alert dialog from TextEdit.app randomly pops up. The dialog looks like this:

[image]

The dialog asks if I want to save changes made to an open or minimized RTF document in TextEdit. The dialog sometimes appears even when TextEdit is not the active application; the dialog comes out of nowhere.

My answer to this dialog, 100% of the time, is <kbd>Save Anyway</kbd>. This is because hitting the <kbd>Revert</kbd> button irrevocably changes the file to the last-saved version of the file (which is obviously undesirable).

1. If the document is not being edited in another application, then why does this message appear? Or, how can I figure out which application (i.e., *"another application"*) is responsible for the changes to the document, exactly?
2. Is it possible to prevent this dialog from needlessly appearing? Or, is it possible for Textedit to *"save anyway,"* by default?

<sub>OS X El Capitan, version 10.11.6.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen this sheet without the underlying file being changed. Try opensnoop on the file to determine the process which is accessing the file:

```
$ sudo opensnoop -f /path/to/file.txt
  UID    PID COMM          FD PATH
  501  32092 Finder        14 /path/to/file.txt
    0     81 mds           28 /path/to/file.txt
  501  41898 mdworker       9 /path/to/file.txt
  501  42646 TextMate      16 /path/to/file.txt
  501  42646 TextMate      16 /path/to/file.txt
  501  42646 TextMate      25 /path/to/file.txt
  501  42646 TextMate      26 /path/to/file.txt
```

This is a live printout, so keep the opensnoop running until you get the sheet, then check your Terminal window and look back to see the process. ⌃C stops opensnoop when you're finished. You will need to [disable System Integrity Protection](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/package-incompatible-installer/) to use opensnoop and can be re-enabled afterwards.

Comment: I get the following message in Terminal after entering the `opensnoop` line: `token too large, exceeds YYLMAX`. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @rubik This is due to incorrect quoting in opensnoop for files with spaces in the path. Open `/usr/bin/opensnoop` with a text editor and add a pair of double quotes directly around the $ variables on lines 162 and 163. 162 should now read `inline string PATHNAME = "'"$pathname"'";`, such that each side of quotes went from `" '` to `" ' "` (without spaces).

Comment: How do you save the edited file? I can't save it in TextEdit or TextWrangler. I am given the error: _`You don’t own the file “opensnoop” and don’t have permission to write to it.`_ I also tried pasting the edited file in the `/usr/bin/` folder, and it wouldn't work. When I try to change the file or folder permissions via the "Get Info" window in Finder, I get the error:  _`The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have the necessary permission.`_ But, my user account is an administrator account and it is the only user.

Comment: @rubik You'll need to disable System Integrity Protection to modify system files. Since you have to disable it to use opensnoop, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Do you happen to know what `RSScriptRunner` and `cp` refer to? Based on [my `opensnoop` log](http://i.imgur.com/6ofLw9T.png), I believe that it is one or both of these processes that is responsible for accessing/editing the .rtf file in the background.

Answer (score 0):

### Closure:

I followed the instructions provided by user *grgarside* in their answer.

I realized that the .rtf file was, in fact, being altered by another application. Hence, it is entirely appropriate that I was given the <kbd>The file has been changed by another application.</kbd> dialog.

As *grgarside* suggested, the dialog never actually appeared needlessly.

Specifically, the file was being changed by an AppleScript of mine. The solution was to implement a check in the AppleScript code, to see if the .rtf file was already open. If the .rtf file was open, then I made sure that my AppleScript code would not write text to this file.

After I made the fix to my AppleScript code, I have never seen this dialog again.